# How do I generate a file based on user input in MSI created using WixSharp?

Tags: wixsharp

I created an installation *MSI* package using *WixSharp*. I have a custom dialog with language, server, etc. options. I want to generate an application config file based on these options and deploy it next to the `.exe` file as part of an installation process. If it is possible, how should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe on AfterInstall event (when files has been coppied) and modify your config file there.

[AfterInstall demostration](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/blob/master/Source/src/WixSharp.Samples/Wix%23%20Samples/Managed%20Setup/SetupEvents/setup.cs)

> project.AfterInstall += project_AfterInstall;
>
> ...
>
> static void project_AfterInstall(SetupEventArgs e)

Installation directory you can find here:

```cs
private void OnAfterInstall(SetupEventArgs e)
{
    var installationPath = e.Session["INSTALLDIR"];

    // Change your config file here
    // if you need to modify your file once time after installation
    // just add this one condition if (e.IsInstalled) { ... }
}
```